# Is there anything special about the "awake, awake" in Isaiah 51 & 52?

Tags: isaiah

Isaiah 51:

> 9 **Awake, awake**,
> put on strength, O arm of the LORD.
> Wake up as in days past,
> as in generations of old.

> 17 **Awake, awake!**
> Rise up, O Jerusalem,
> you who have drunk from the hand of the LORD
> the cup of His fury;
> you who have drained the goblet to the dregs—
> the cup that makes men stagger.

Isaiah 52:

> 1 **Awake, awake**,
> clothe yourself with strength, O Zion!
> Put on your garments of splendor,
> O Jerusalem, holy city!
> For the uncircumcised and unclean
> will no longer enter you.

There are three "Awake, awake" sequences in basically one chapter. Is there significance in this?

Comment: Do you mean whether there is a symbol behind the number 3 in this context?

Comment: I'm looking for just about anything. I usually +1 to anyone just for the effort of answering my question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Isaiah is using Awake Awake as a way to wake up Israel to celebrate a new day when something wonderful has happened.

Each of these verses has a reason to celebrate hance he says clothe yourself in joyous apparel.

- Verse 9 - Egypt is referred to as Rahab in this verse the dragon is Pharoah (exodus out of Egypt)
- Isreal has suffered the punishment of G-d and taken more than was due
- G-d is promising that no nation will threaten Israel anymore.